# Editing business objects in Winforms DataGridView

Tags: winforms, datagridview, bindinglist

Is possible to edit properties of business object (one property, one column) binded as BindingList to Winforms DataGridView?

Or do I have to use DataSet or DataTable?

I'm not able to get a cell to edit mode.

Comment: Do you have an example? Not exactly sure what the problem is.  One quick and dirty option is to just throw the business object in List<> and set the grid DataSource to that List<>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible check out BindingList.

Otherwise the book Data Binding in Windows Forms 2.0 by Brian Noyes is an excellent reference book CH9 deals specifically with Binding Custom Business Objects.